# SQL Query exclusion for "set-within-sets"

Tags: mysql

I have a table `item_category` with two columns: `item_id`, `cat_id`. Item to category is a many-to-many relationship.

If my table looks like this...

```
item_id | cat_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 3
2       | 4
3       | 5
3       | 6
4       | 7
4       | 8
5       | 9
5       | 10
```

... how can I select a distinct list of `item_id`s that do not have *any* rows where `category_id` is 2 or 7 (yielding `item_id`s of 2, 3, 5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select item_id
from item_category ic
group by item_id
having max(cat_id = 2) = 0 and
       max(cat_id = 7) = 0
```

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  Using `group by` with `having` is the most generalizable form for such a query.  For instance, if you wanted to be sure that category 3 were included, you would change the `having` clause to:

```
having max(cat_id = 2) = 0 and
       max(cat_id = 7) = 0 and
       max(cat_id = 3) = 1
```

Comment: Changing my selected answer to this one. Although all the answers work, this is by far the fastest. Thank you for the explanation, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id
FROM table_category
WHERE item_id NOT IN
      (  select distinct item_id 
           from item_category 
          where cat_id in (2,7)
      )
```

Comment: Mis-clicked.  I edited the post so that I could fix the downvote, and make it an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a nested `SELECT`, though there are probably ways to do this with a [self join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join).

```
select item_id 
from item_category t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from item_category 
    where item_id = t.item_id 
        and cat_id in (2,7)
)
group by item_id;
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d40fc/1)

You could also use a `NOT IN` clause instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id 
FROM item_category
WHERE item_id NOT IN (
    select distinct item_id 
    from item_category 
    where cat_id in (2,7));
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d40fc/5)

Both queries are probably similar in performance, but you can test if your data set is large.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_category.item_id
FROM item_category 
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT item_id ,SUM(CASE cat_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS catcount
              FROM item_category 
              GROUP BY item_id
           ) AS exclude
        ON item_category .item_id = exclude.item_id
            WHERE exclude.catcount=0
```

**Updated** the answer I think this is what you meant.

Comment: With this query, I would still get back `item_id` of 1 and 4.

Comment: yeah updated the query read your question again. The new one works on my test data

Answer (score 1):

One way would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_ID
  FROM ITEM_CATEGORY
  WHERE ITEM_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_ID
                          FROM ITEM_CATEGORY
                          WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN (2, 7))
```

which produces your desired results.  If you want to have a bit more fun, you could do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic1.ITEM_ID
  FROM ITEM_CATEGORY ic1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_ID
                     FROM ITEM_CATEGORY
                     WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN (2, 7)) ic2
    ON ic2.ITEM_ID = ic1.ITEM_ID
  WHERE ic2.ITEM_ID IS NULL
```

which also gets the results you're looking for and, if you're not familiar with how a LEFT OUTER JOIN works, might make for an interesting time puzzling through how and why it works.

[SqlFiddle here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d97fc/4)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a simple sub query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id
FROM ic
WHERE item_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM ic WHERE cat_id IN (2,7)
 );
```

Comment: But mine looks nicer ;)